# Saving blob files in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, xml, model-view-controller, jsp

I am saving blob files in the mysql database in my springmvc with hibernate project.But after several blob files has uploaded i got an error in my project as out of memmory error java heap space.Can any one help me to resolve this

Comment: Why do you save files directly in the form of `blob`? Is it absolutely necessary? You should avoid it and store them in a directory instead, if there is no need to store them in `blob`.

Comment: Can you design your project to not store blobs in your MySQL database?  Blobs are incredibly inefficient and cursorily sounds like the blobs are using up all your cache.

Comment: Sure, let me just haul out my magic crystal ball and examine your code via remote telepathic viewing... ummm. ... it's that extra semicolon on line 3562463235423523 of your code.

Comment: @MarcB Why don't you save comments like those for reddit. They help nobody.

Answer (score 1):

The contents of your files aren't getting released by your application. Somehow a reference to them remains in memory. You can use a profiler to track down where this reference exists.